# Xcode stops responding after tapping on .Storyboard file

Tags: xcode, xcode6, xcode7, xcode6.4, xcode7-beta4

Okay, so I'm trying to work on my app here and I'm trying to go to my Storyboard. Everytime I tap on the .Storyboard file, Xcode says "Application is not responding" and it quits. This issue just started happening last night(after installing OS X El Capitan beta 6). I'm not sure what's going on with this. Ran in with this with Xcode 6.4 and Xcode 7 beta 4.

UPDATE : A look on the developer forums shows that this issue has been happening for everyone. It seems that OS X El Capitan beta 6 breaks both versions of Xcode. Ugh. Now we wait for a new build of OS X or a new build of Xcode.

Comment: Do you have any external hard drives connected via USB? If yes, remove them all.

Comment: I do not having anything connected to it.

Comment: ok. That's what caused very strange behaviour with my Xcode sometimes...

Comment: You should downgrade, it's happening to almost everyone who updated to El Capitan Beta 6 or wait for Fix from apple @AmitNivedanKalra

Comment: You do not need to downgrade. Just need to rename dyld_sim to dyld_sim.orig. I've described below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to lembacon shared a temporary workaround. (Applies to Xcode 7 beta 4 on OS X El Capitan Developer Beta 6)

Open your Terminal:

```
cd /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/lib 
sudo mv dyld_sim dyld_sim.orig 
cd /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator.sdk/usr/lib
sudo mv dyld_sim dyld_sim.orig
```

For XCode 6:

```
cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/lib 
sudo mv dyld_sim dyld_sim.orig
```

Comment: Works great. Now I don't have to wait for a new beta to fix this :P

Answer (score 1):

According to Apple developer Forums:
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/13170

You can reinstall Beta 5 by downloading and running the following directly from Apple's CDN. This can be done over Beta 6 without loss of data (you lose sound but disabling SIP from Recovery Mode may bring that back):

- http://swcdn.apple.com/content/downloads/43/22/031-29032/71ihp9c54k547fvol25w5g85z9323gqwnr/OSXUpd10.11.pkg
- http://swcdn.apple.com/content/downloads/43/22/031-29032/71ihp9c54k547fvol25w5g85z9323gqwnr/FirmwareUpdate.pkg

Run the FirmwareUpdate.pkg first

Comment: Yeah, I'm just going to wait a day for an update for OS X or maybe Xcode 7 beta 5. If that doesn't solve it, I'm going back to OS X El Capitan beta 5.

Comment: you lose sound but disabling SIP from Recovery Mode may bring that back . did you tried and worked for you? Does not seem that SIP is the Issue with the sound.

Comment: I thought to go this way, too, but in time found a simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here. I updated to OS X El Capitan beta 6 this afternoon and it broke both version of Xcode (6.4 and 7 beta 4). One of my project was left over at .Storyboard so whenever I open Xcode it will loading it forever and stop responding. I tried to created a new project and the same thing happens when I click the storyboard file. Guess we have to wait for a new version of Xcode.

Comment: Yup! Hopefully Xcode 7 beta 5 comes out later today or earlier tomorrow.